# How to remove a row from a dataframe if a value does not exist in another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, match, data-manipulation

I have two dataframes `df_description` and `df_users`. First one has a column named **users**. The second dataframe has two columns, **user_1** and **user_2**. Ideally, values in both columns of `df_users` must match the values in **users** column of `df_description`.

If a value does not exist in `df_description`, the corresponding row of that value should be removed from `df_users`.

Following is the example:

```
#df_descirption
users
Adam
Micheal
George
```

And

```
#df_users
user_1   user_2
Adam     George
Adam     Micheal
George   Elizabeth #since Elizabeth does not exist in df_descirption, this row should be removed
```

The final `df_users` should look something like this:

```
#df_users
user_1   user_2
Adam     George
Adam     Micheal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Base R, try:

```
df_users[df_users$user_1 %in% df_descirption$users &
           df_users$user_2 %in% df_descirption$users, ]
```

Output:

```
#   user_1  user_2
#1    Adam  George
#2    Adam Micheal
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter` with `if_all`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  filter(if_all(c(user_1, user_2), ~ .x %in% df1$users))
```

output

```r
  user_1  user_2
1   Adam  George
2   Adam Micheal
```